# Flask request.data is slow (image)

Tags: python, image, flask, server, request

I'm creating a simple and small server that take a photo sent with a POST request, decode it and save it, using flask and python.

Everything work fine, but sometimes it's really really slow, after some debugging I noticed that the only part which take a lot is `request.data.decode('utf-8')`, it need from 15 to 30 second, there is something I can do to make it faster? or better? Here's the code

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def SaveImmage():
    if request.method =='POST':
        global counter
        counter+=1

        data_json = json.loads(request.data.decode('utf-8'))
        image = data_json['image']
        
        image_dec = base64.b64decode(image)
        data_np = np.frombuffer(image_dec, dtype = 'uint8')
        decimg = cv2.imdecode(data_np, 1)
        filename = r"C:\Users\... \image.png"
        cv2.imwrite(filename, decimg)

        return Response(...., status = 200)
```

EDIT:
I changed my code using `request.get_json` instead of `json.loads(request.data.decode('utf-8'))`, but it seems slow anyway, at least now I know there's not a problem with the decode part. There's a better and more efficient way to save an image from a post request using flask?

Comment: base64-encoded image data could be quite big - how big are the images that you are saving?

Comment: Omit decoding? `json.loads(s, …`  Deserialize `s` (a `str`, **`bytes`** or `bytearray` instance containing a JSON document) to a Python object (since  version 3.6). https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/json.html#json.loads

Comment: @snakecharmerb around 200 kB, there's a better encoding to send photo with post request? I'm open to suggestion, thank you!

Comment: @JosefZ I'm sorry I haven't understood your comment, i'm at the beginning of python. I saw on the website that you linked me that s can be a byte, in my code I think that it's correct, you mean that I should decode it first and then pass it to the json.loads? I did it before and it was slow either, i changed it because I thougt it would help but it didn't. anyway, thakn you for your comment!

Comment: Just use `json.loads(request.data)`…

Comment: @JosefZ it still takes around 20 sec, you think there's a way to make it faster?